# pandas.DataFrame.groupby.nunique() does not drop the groupby column/s. Is this a bug?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Although I set the parameter as_index to True, pandas.DataFrame.groupby.nunique() keeps the columns I am grouping by in the result.

The pandas version is: 0.24.1

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': [1, 1, 2, 3, 2],
     'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]}
)
df.groupby('a', as_index=True).nunique()
```

The output is:

```
#    a  b
# a      
# 1  1  2
# 2  1  2
# 3  1  1
```

I expected:

```
#    b
# a   
# 1  2
# 2  2
# 3  1
```

As a counterexample that behaves as expected:

```
df.groupby('a', as_index=True).max()
```

results in:

```
#    b
# a   
# 1  2
# 2  4
# 3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `[print(df.to_string() + '\n') for i, df in df.groupby('a', as_index=True)]`, you get printed:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  2

   a  b
2  2  3
4  2  4

   a  b
3  3  4
```

The `a` column isn't set as the index for each data frame group. It is the *output* of the groupby which has its index set to the group indices when `as_index=True` (which also is the default), not the data frame groups themselves.